# Detect if two ranges of type Range<String.Index> are continuous

Tags: swift

How can we detect if two ranges of type Range<String.Index> are continuous

example:

```
{0, 50}, {51, 17} //expected: continuous 
{0, 50}, {52, 17} //expected: not continuous
{0, 50}, {56, 17} //expected: not continuous
```

My current approach is to convert the Range<String.Index> to NSRange and compare like: `previousNSRange.upperBound + 1 == currentNSRange.lowerBound`

Comment: The two ranges `(0, 50}` and `{51, 17}` are not continuous. The range `{50, 1}` is being skipped in that example.

Answer (score 1):

Your example ranges are `NSRange`s, in terms of Swift `Range` two ranges are *contiguous* if the `upperBound` of the first array is equal to the `lowerBound` of the second.

As the bounds of a range are independent of the indices of a collection this is not restricted to `String`

The function checks the order of the `lowerBound` values, so it's irrelevant which range calls the method

```
extension Range {
    func isContiguous(to other: Range<Bound>) -> Bool {
        if self.lowerBound > other.lowerBound {
            return self.lowerBound == other.upperBound
        } else {
           return self.upperBound == other.lowerBound
        }
    }
}

let string = "abcdef"

let range1 = string.range(of: "abc")!
let range2 = string.range(of: "def")!
range1.isContiguous(to: range2) // true

let range3 = 0..<3
let range4 = 3..<6
range4.isContiguous(to: range3) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

With a simple check:

```
func testConnected<T: SignedNumeric & Comparable>(
    a: (start: T, end: T), /// You can get rid of the unused `a.start`
    b: (start: T, end: T), /// You can get rid of the unused `b.end`
    padding: T = 1
) -> Bool {
    abs(a.end - b.start) == padding
}
```

results:

```
testConnected(a: (0, 50), b: (51, 17)) // ~~ true
testConnected(a: (0, 50), b: (52, 17)) // ~~ false
testConnected(a: (0, 50), b: (56, 17)) // ~~ false
```

Comment: the ranges are of type Range<String.Index> not Range<Int>